# Magento 2.3.4: Add new column to Manage Options of Product Attribute

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, magento2.3.4, select, attribute-options

Like the title, I'm trying add new column to Manage Options.
The problem is that the style of the row I want to add is select.
It is showing but when I click on the select box, the list of options is not showing and I cannot select another value.
[image]

please help me to do this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is working like this because the table is sortable. An easy solution would be to disable the sortable option for the table.

Override somehow this template in your vendor

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/attribute/options.phtml
```

and at the bottom of the file you can see the js configuration for the options js file, something like this

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/options": {
                "attributesData": <?= /* @noEscape */ json_encode($values, JSON_HEX_QUOT) ?>,
                "isSortable":  <?= (int)(!$block->getReadOnly() && !$block->canManageOptionDefaultOnly()) ?>,
                "isReadOnly": <?= (int)$block->getReadOnly() ?>
            },
            "Magento_Catalog/catalog/product/attribute/unique-validate": {
                "element": "required-dropdown-attribute-unique",
                "message": "<?= $block->escapeHtml(__("The value of Admin must be unique.")) ?>"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Just replace the value for the `isSortable` key with `false` and make it look like this

`"isSortable": false,`

This will make the select tag work but you won't be able to sort the table anymore.

If you want to keep the sorting functionality you can override/extend the
`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/web/js/options.js`.
Look for this piece of code

```
$('[data-role=options-container]').sortable({
   distance: 8,
   tolerance: 'pointer',
   cancel: 'input, button',
   axis: 'y',
   update: function () {
   $('[data-role=options-container] [data-role=order]').each(function (index, element) {
     $(element).val(index + 1);
   });
 }});
```

Here just add the select html tag in the cancel parameter, something like this

`cancel: 'input, button, select'`